# Is any possibility to add the SVN into the code lens in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-extensions, codelens

Is any extension available to add svn into the code-lens?

Comment: Agreed I miss this when work uses SVN

Answer (score 1):

CodeLens is not officially extensible as of today AFAIK. I am not aware of any third-party Visual Studio plug-in that would extend it.